# Rails 3 app - values not storing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller a whole bunch of numbers are crunched. Percentages are multiplied by 100 so they can be stored as integers. Here is a partial list:

```
tot = @mot[1] + @mot[2] + @mot[3]
exec_pct = @mot[3] / tot * 100
tact_pct = @mot[2] / tot * 100
strat_pct = @mot[1] / tot * 100
```

Then the values are supposed to be written to the user record as follows:

```
current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => strat_pct.to_i, :tact_pct => tact_pct.to_i, :exec_pct => exec_pct.to_i )
```

The database has null values where the data should be stored.

Here's relevant portion of db schema:

```
t.integer  "strat_pct"
t.integer  "tact_pct"
t.integer  "exec_pct"
```

UPDATE -

For testing purposes I have place eliminated calculation questions by inserting integers like so:

```
current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => 1, :tact_pct => 2, :exec_pct => 3 )
```

and:

```
p current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => 1, :tact_pct => 2, :exec_pct => 3 )
```

The fields are still null.

UPDATE 2 - User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :login

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true

  before_create :create_login

  def create_login
    self.login = "#{last_name.capitalize}, #{first_name.capitalize}"
  end

  has_many :answers
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :feedbacks

end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Gazler, maybe you can take a crack at it?

Comment: Could you please post your user block from db/scheme.rb?

Comment: @Gazler... schema in post now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that could be wrong.

First off, try:

```
p current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => strat_pct.to_i, :tact_pct => tact_pct.to_i, :exec_pct => exec_pct.to_i )
```

From the documentation:

> If the saving fails because of a connection or remote service error, an exception will be raised. If saving fails because the resource is invalid then false will be returned.

The other thing that strikes me is that your logic will probably return 0 for everything:

```
tot = @mot[1] + @mot[2] + @mot[3]   #assume [0,100,200,300] = 600
exec_pct = @mot[3] / tot * 100      #300 / 600000 (integers)= 0
tact_pct = @mot[2] / tot * 100      #200 / 600000 (integers)= 0
strat_pct = @mot[1] / tot * 100     #100 / 600000 (integers)= 0
```

Perhaps you mean:

```
tot = (@mot[1] + @mot[2] + @mot[3]).to_f   #assume [0,100,200,300] = 600.0
exec_pct = (@mot[3] / tot) * 100      #300 / 600000.0 (float)= 50.0
tact_pct = (@mot[2] / tot) * 100      #200 / 600000.0 (float)= 33.333
strat_pct = (@mot[1] / tot) * 100     #100 / 600000.0 (float)= 16.666
```

In ruby, if you are doing float operations, at least one of the values must be a float.  I am also assuming you are doing percentages, so I have added brackets around the division operation as that needs to be executed first.

Also, I could be wrong, but it looks like you are accidentally 1-indexing your array.  Array indexes start from 0.  If that is the case, you could change the code to:

```
@mot = [100,200,300]
total = @mot.inject(:+).to_f
@mot.map {|x| ((x/total.to_f)*100).to_i} #result => [16, 33, 50]
current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct =>@mot[0], :tact_pct => t@mot[1], :exec_pct => @mot[2] )
```

**EDIT**

Your issue is here:

```
 validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true
```

You are trying to update the attributes, but password and password_confirmation will be missing as it is not a real field.  Change that line to:

```
 validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, , :presence => true
 validates :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :on => :create
```

Comment: p current_user.update_attributes(:strat_pct => 1, :tact_pct => 2, :exec_pct => 3 ) should return true or false, which is it returning?  Also, can you do p current_user.class and make sure it is of class "User"

Comment: @Gazler, false and User respectively. Thanks.

Comment: @Jay: can you post your user model too?

Comment: @Gazler, i replace current validation with your two lines. Still coming up null. Oh man. Thanks for trying. I've learned quite a bit already from your answers.

Comment: @Jay: Hmm, before you perform update_attributes can you put the output of "p current_user" be sure to blank out the password field.  After doing the update, put the output of "current_user.errors"

Comment: @Gazler, error msg = #<OrderedHash {:password=>["can't be blank"]}> I don't get it... how could the password field be blank?

Comment: Aha!  I was close with my last solution.  Password is blank because it is not stored in the database, it is stored by devise as encrypted_password.  See my last edit (the validation rules) for the solution (I hope!)

Comment: @Gazler, YOU ROCK! YOU ARE THE KING! YOU ARE MY HERO! Thanks, man.

Comment: @Jay, thanks, it took a while!  Good luck with your application.